# Two separate vertical list scrolling in dropdown

Tags: android, list, android-layout, dropdown

I want the design layout in android like same as shared here in image. there are two separate vertical scrolling. Any help will be appreciated.

[image: Click to see the image here]

Comment: You can create a custom picker dialogs

Comment: @AkashDubey I dont want to do it in seperate dialog. It should happen in something like spinner.I tried doing custom adapter with layout file for spinner. but thats not happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your layout put a spinner, for example

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>
```

Then, create an adapter for your spinner
See [here](http://www.zoftino.com/android-spinner-custom-adapter-&-layout) 'how to'

for 2 scroll list, you can do it like this in your adapter item layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/picker_month"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/NumberPickerText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

    </NumberPicker>

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/picker_year"
        android:theme="@style/NumberPickerText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </NumberPicker>

</LinearLayout>
```